# Android Java: Speech Recognition App crashes whenever there are no results

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am developing an Android app that uses the Google speech recognition api. For some reason, when I start up the app (via USB debugging on my Android phone), starting the listening process works just fine, and the app works smoothly if I do actually say something after clicking the button to make the app start listening for audio. However, if I click the button to start listening, and then I don't say anything, then the app crashes for some reason. In other words, if the speech recognition gets no results, then the app just crashes. Does anyone have any idea as to why?

Below is an excerpt of my code. (Yes, I did account for the permissions. I just didn't include that code in the excerpt below).

I have tried putting try catch blocks in various places to see if I could catch the error that causes the crash, but it has yet to work. Furthermore, while there is an onResults method, there does not seem to be an onNoResults method.

```
speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
recognitionListener = new RecognitionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        // Called when the speech recognition process is ready to begin
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        // Called when the user begins speaking
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        // Called when the volume of the spoken input changes
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        // Called when the app receives a buffer of audio data

    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
       // Called when the user stops speaking
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        // Called when an error occurs during the speech recognition process
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.errors);
        textView.setText(error);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        // Called when the speech recognition process has completed and the results are available
        List<String> resultList = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

        if (resultList != null && resultList.size() > 0) {
            // Display the first result in the text field
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.spokenWords);
            textView.setText(resultList.get(0));
        }
        //speechRecognizer.startListening(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH));
    }



    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
       // Called when the app receives partial results of the speech recognition process

    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        // Called when the app receives other events from the speech recognition process

    }


};

speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(recognitionListener);
Button startSpeech = findViewById(R.id.startSpeech);
startSpeech.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.spokenWords);
        textView.setText("Listening");
        speechRecognizer.startListening(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH));
    }
});
```

Comment: Can Bundle results be null in onResults? Are there any errors in logcat?

Comment: @user1257 Logcat is not telling me anything, and I have verified that the code does not even visit onResults when I remain silent and this problem occurs.

Comment: Your issue is likely in the `onError` where you call `textView.setText(error)` - this form (with an int parameter) is expecting a valid `resid` (resource id) - and if not found will fail with an exception.  The `error` parameter is not a valid resid.  Try converting the `int error` to a string specifically with `Integer.toString(error)`.